# When is using layer.enabled a good idea?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I recently read about how using `layer.enabled` can shave off loading time for some screens but it also mentioned that it's not always an optimization. Documentation mentions says

> Enabling layering for complex QML item hierarchies can sometimes be an optimization.

But it is not clear to me when exactly it's an optimization? What are the best use-cases? Are there any downsides of using it? If not, why is it just not enabled by default?

Comment: What part of the docs did you read? Did you read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#memory-and-performance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `layer.enabled` means (complex) item is rendered once into a texture and cached. Benefit? It can then be animated freely without the need to render it again every frame.

@JarMan already pointed to the part of [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#memory-and-performance) which explains why it's not necessarily good from the memory and performance point of view.

Comment: So basically, it's about balancing performance and memory?

Comment: Yes, especially with memory-constrained devices. E.g. with lower-range embedded devices you typically need to be careful to not overuse [Qt Graphical Effects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgraphicaleffects-index.html) or to totally avoid them.